# pip permissions issue on OS X using a basic command

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install pip using this command:

```
python get-pip.py
```

The error it's spitting out is this - can you help? (I'm running macOS 10.12.1)

Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/by/db2rdr7n1753qbfz0rlgk7hw0000gn/T/tmptA1AVr/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/var/folders/by/db2rdr7n1753qbfz0rlgk7hw0000gn/T/tmptA1AVr/pip.zip/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/var/folders/by/db2rdr7n1753qbfz0rlgk7hw0000gn/T/tmptA1AVr/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/var/folders/by/db2rdr7n1753qbfz0rlgk7hw0000gn/T/tmptA1AVr/pip.zip/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/var/folders/by/db2rdr7n1753qbfz0rlgk7hw0000gn/T/tmptA1AVr/pip.zip/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/var/folders/by/db2rdr7n1753qbfz0rlgk7hw0000gn/T/tmptA1AVr/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/var/folders/by/db2rdr7n1753qbfz0rlgk7hw0000gn/T/tmptA1AVr/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 317, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/var/folders/by/db2rdr7n1753qbfz0rlgk7hw0000gn/T/tmptA1AVr/pip.zip/pip/utils/**init**.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install pip you on Mac OSX you can try :

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

The "sudo" keyword is what will grant you root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You need root access. Activate your root account and try from there.